# Consuming SOAP API in .NET With Service Reference/WCF. Message not formatted properly

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soap, wsdl, service-reference

I am attempting to consume a SOAP 1.2 API using the WSDL provided by one of our vendors. I have simplified the WSDL as much as possible, down to just one action. The issue I am running into is that the formatting that WCF is generating for the SOAP Request Message does not match what the vendor is expecting, or what SoapUI generates. Specifically the envelope does not include the `xmlns:ser="http://some.random.api.here.com/"`, the `getDeviceList` action doesn't include `ser:`.

The error I receive is:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Unmarshalling Error:
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'userName'. One of '{userName, password, clientId,
>   locationId}' is expected.

As far as I can tell based on some research this error just means that the soap body is not formatted correctly, or as the server expects.

The request generated by SoapUI works as expected, but the .NET one does not. I have tried using a Web Service instead, but I get the same results. I was looking at manually changing the message as mentioned [here](https://cmatskas.com/changing-soap-message-data-and-namespaces-with-c/), but it seems that WCF should be able to handle this. The WSDL appears to be valid, and Svcutil doesn't throw any errors except for not importing the Security Policy portion.

The other, more minor, issue that I am running into is that even though the WSDL specifies the properties username, password, clientid, and locationid as minoccurs=0 they are still being required by the generated proxy classes. I would like to figure out a way to resolve this as well, but I can work on that after I at least get something working.

I have tried multiple types of bindings as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind): basicHttpBinding since they have a Soap 1.1 service as well, WsHttpBinding, and a custom binding using multiple combinations of settings, but nothing seems to make a difference as to the format of the message.

If anyone has any thoughts about how to set the format of the SOAP message or tell .NET to include the proper namespace I would be forever grateful, as I am just about out of ideas.

SoapUI Request:

```
POST https://a.randomapi.com/api/ApiService12 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 386
Host: a.randomapi.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_74)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://some.random.api.here.com/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:getDeviceList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <userName>username</userName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <password>password</password>
      </ser:getDeviceList>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

.NET Request (Captured with Fiddler):

```
POST https://a.randomapi.com/api/ApiService12 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=""
Host: a.randomapi.com
Content-Length: 645
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<s:Header>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<getDeviceList xmlns="http://some.random.api.here.com/">
<userName xmlns="">username</userName>
<password xmlns="">password</password>
<clientId xmlns="">0</clientId>
<locationId xmlns="">0</locationId>
</getDeviceList>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

WSDL:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://some.random.api.here.com/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="ApiServiceImplService" targetNamespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:tns="http://some.random.api.here.com/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"/>

  <xs:element name="faultInfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="faultCode" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="reason" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="getDeviceList" type="tns:getDeviceList"/>
  <xs:element name="getDeviceListResponse" type="tns:getDeviceListResponse"/>
  <xs:complexType name="getDeviceList">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="userName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="clientId" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="locationId" type="xs:long"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="getDeviceListResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="device" type="tns:deviceInfo"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="deviceInfo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="client" type="tns:provInfo"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="deviceAlias" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="deviceId" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="deviceIp" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="deviceName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="location" type="tns:provInfo"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="provInfo">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ApiWebFaultException" nillable="true"/> 
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ApiWebFaultException">
  <wsdl:part element="tns:ApiWebFaultException" name="ApiWebFaultException"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getDeviceList">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getDeviceList" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getDeviceListResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getDeviceListResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ApiService">
    <wsdl:operation name="getDeviceList">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getDeviceList" name="getDeviceList">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getDeviceListResponse" name="getDeviceListResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:ApiWebFaultException" name="ApiWebFaultException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ApiServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:ApiService">
    <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#UsernameTokenPolicy"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDeviceList">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getDeviceList">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getDeviceListResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="ApiWebFaultException">
        <soap12:fault name="ApiWebFaultException" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ApiServiceImplService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:ApiServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" name="ApiServiceImplPort">
      <soap12:address location="https://a.randomapi.com/api/ApiService12"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
    <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" wsu:Id="UsernameTokenPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
            <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssUsernameToken11/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SupportingTokens>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Generated Code:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1067.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/")]
public partial class getDeviceList : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string userNameField;

    private string passwordField;

    private long clientIdField;

    private bool clientIdFieldSpecified;

    private long locationIdField;

    private bool locationIdFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public string userName {
        get {
            return this.userNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.userNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("userName");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public string password {
        get {
            return this.passwordField;
        }
        set {
            this.passwordField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("password");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
    public long clientId {
        get {
            return this.clientIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.clientIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("clientId");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool clientIdSpecified {
        get {
            return this.clientIdFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.clientIdFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("clientIdSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
    public long locationId {
        get {
            return this.locationIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.locationIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("locationId");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool locationIdSpecified {
        get {
            return this.locationIdFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.locationIdFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("locationIdSpecified");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1067.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/")]
public partial class provInfo : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private long idField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public long id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1067.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/")]
public partial class deviceInfo : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private provInfo clientField;

    private string deviceAliasField;

    private long deviceIdField;

    private bool deviceIdFieldSpecified;

    private string deviceIpField;

    private string deviceNameField;

    private provInfo locationField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public provInfo client {
        get {
            return this.clientField;
        }
        set {
            this.clientField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("client");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public string deviceAlias {
        get {
            return this.deviceAliasField;
        }
        set {
            this.deviceAliasField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("deviceAlias");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
    public long deviceId {
        get {
            return this.deviceIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.deviceIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("deviceId");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool deviceIdSpecified {
        get {
            return this.deviceIdFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.deviceIdFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("deviceIdSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
    public string deviceIp {
        get {
            return this.deviceIpField;
        }
        set {
            this.deviceIpField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("deviceIp");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=4)]
    public string deviceName {
        get {
            return this.deviceNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.deviceNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("deviceName");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=5)]
    public provInfo location {
        get {
            return this.locationField;
        }
        set {
            this.locationField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("location");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/", ConfigurationName="ServiceReference5.ApiService")]
public interface ApiService {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(object), Action="", Name="ApiWebFaultException")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(getDeviceList))]
    WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.getDeviceListResponse getDeviceList(WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.getDeviceList1 request);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.getDeviceListResponse> getDeviceListAsync(WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.getDeviceList1 request);
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getDeviceList", WrapperNamespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getDeviceList1 {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string userName;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string password;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/", Order=2)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public long clientId;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/", Order=3)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public long locationId;

    public getDeviceList1() {
    }

    public getDeviceList1(string userName, string password, long clientId, long locationId) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getDeviceListResponse", WrapperNamespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getDeviceListResponse {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://some.random.api.here.com/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("device", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.deviceInfo[] device;

    public getDeviceListResponse() {
    }

    public getDeviceListResponse(WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.deviceInfo[] device) {
        this.device = device;
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface ApiServiceChannel : WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.ApiService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class ApiServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.ApiService>, WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.ApiService {

    public ApiServiceClient() {
    }

    public ApiServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public ApiServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public ApiServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public ApiServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.getDeviceListResponse getDeviceList(WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.getDeviceList1 request) {
        return base.Channel.getDeviceList(request);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.getDeviceListResponse> getDeviceListAsync(WebApplication1.ServiceReference5.getDeviceList1 request) {
        return base.Channel.getDeviceListAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Code to Call API:
            var client = new ServiceReference5.ApiServiceClient();

```
        var request = new ServiceReference5.getDeviceList1();

        request.userName = "username";
        request.password = "password";

        var response = client.getDeviceList(request);
```

Binding/Endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="https://a.randomapi.com/api/ApiService12"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ApiServiceImplServiceSoapBinding1"
        contract="ServiceReference5.ApiService" name="ApiServiceImplPort1" />

<customBinding>
                <binding name="ApiServiceImplServiceSoapBinding1">
          <!--    WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'http://some.random.api.here.com/':    -->
          <!--    <wsdl:binding name='ApiServiceImplServiceSoapBinding'>    -->
          <!--        <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">..</sp:SupportingTokens>    -->
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Comment: _"I have simplified the WSDL"_. Did you just simplify it for making this question more compact or did you simplify it in general? Did you try to generate a proxy with the _full_ wsdl?

Comment: I simplified it for the purpose of making the question more compact. I generated a proxy with the full WSDL originally and the error was the same.